# Sharepoint 2010 attachment getting lost

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm new to Sharepoint 2010 and I am working in the attachment of a file to sharepoint, I have a user mode and a admin mode. The user and the admin can also attach files. The issue is that, when the user attaches a file, the file that the admin attaches gets lost in the transaction. I have work flows in the background.

Comment: Are attachments getting saved to document library?

Comment: yes they are getting saved in the document library.

Comment: So once admin adds attachment, after that user attaches file?

Comment: uses do changes on their part,they can also add attatchments . The users attatchments stay but the admin loses their's if user edit anything.

Comment: I am not sure, but if user attaches attachment with the name that already exists in document library, that will get replaced. I am not sure but this might be case with you, suppose admin has uploaded "Temp.docx" with his content, now user adds "Temp.docx" to same document library, then existing admin's "Temp.docx" will get replaced by user's file.

Comment: They are using different file names.